# How do I check if an embed is an image preview?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to check for embeds in a discord channel and delete them. However, messages with links that have a preview are also getting deleted.
Here is my code.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.embeds) > 0 and message.channel.id in chat_channels:
         await message.delete()
         await message.channel.send("No embeds in this channel")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord converts uses embeds to show previews from links, hence it is also shown as an embed in `message.embeds`. If we take a look at the [api docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-types), we can see that there are several types of embeds, almost all are some form of preview embeds.

here is the json of an image preview.

```json
{
    "thumbnail":{
        "url":"https:\/\/cdn.discordapp.com\/avatars\/488278979900342282\/a738115e01fe31d415af7b7d4b862acb.png?size=1024",
        "proxy_url":"https:\/\/images-ext-2.discordapp.net\/external\/QODrzk5Or_q-xaVaACaXt_GVP8m7ZQ34ezGFwJgrAK4\/%3Fsize%3D1024\/https\/cdn.discordapp.com\/avatars\/488278979900342282\/a738115e01fe31d415af7b7d4b862acb.png",
        "width":410,
        "height":410
    },
    "type":"image",
    "url":"https:\/\/cdn.discordapp.com\/avatars\/488278979900342282\/a738115e01fe31d415af7b7d4b862acb.png?size=1024"
}
```

The type of image previews are image. If the embed was manually sent by a bot or a webhook, it would have the type `rich`, we can use this to ignore previews for your case.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.embeds) > 0 and message.channel.id in chat_channels:
       if any('rich' == embed.type for embed in message.embeds):
            #remove message, as it has a rich embed
```